# Lazy loading PDF files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, browser, lazy-loading

I'm currently developing a corporate intranet that serves large PDF files. Users get frustrated when they have to wait for entire PDF files to download before they can view them. I have used the embedded Google documents viewer ( http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html ) on other public facing websites for lazy loading and ease of document navigation, but this is not feasible as the solution is required for an intranet. Is it possible to achieve lazy loading of a PDF nativity within a browser and if so what are the requirements for this to happen? I am using `ASP .NET MVC 3`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the PDF documents that your serve are 'linearized' (optimized for web). It allows the browser to download the PDF document partially to display typically the first page fast. When the user navigates to another page, again just a part of the PDF document is downloaded. Here is a good article on the topic:
http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/02/linearized-pdf-files/

In this scenario you would not write directly to the Response stream.

Answer (score 0):

First - this question has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC..

Second - this question has nothing to do with lazy loading. Lazy loading is "pattern" in object-relational mapping, it is not synonym for streaming

Finally - it depends on the PDF viewer you use. Browser does not display PDF files, some plugin in the browser does, typically Adobe Reader. So your question in fact is :

**Can i stream PDF file so that it can be open and read before it is whole on the client ?**

As far as i know, yes you can. But you must use .NET streams - for example "plug" the HttpContext Response stream as output of your PDF generator.

Comment: It has everything to do with mvc, because that is the technology behind his solution.  Your answer is vague and far from useful.

Comment: Seems that #rouen had no trouble 'groking' what was meant by the use of term 'Lazy Load' in the context of PDF document in a browser.  I'll admit that this is a very-loose 'usage' of the term but WTH, saying that the term is exclusive to the domain of object-relational mapping is unnecessarily narrow and not helpful...